# Firebase with Sqlite instead of Firebase's Presence System

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-sqlite

Hi There I am developing an chatting App which features -:

- Messages Remove from server when user receives message(Whatsapp Like)

(Thats Why I am not using firebase presence system)

My App's Fragments and Activity structure is [image: this]

And my firebase Structure is 
[image: this]

In my dashboard Activity I am listening data from server like

```
mRootRef.child("Messeges").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
            .getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber())
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Send CallBack with Event bus in ConversationListFragmen
           //Send CallBack to chattingActivity if User is chatting with someOne

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

when ConversationListFragment finished data processing then I set the value of message node to "null" hence messege deletes from Server

- Now Problem occurs Here

When Messege's value set to null(Data Changes on server)

```
onDataChange
```

method fires.This thing create duplicacy in messeges

Can someone suggest how to prevent from this problem or how should I structure my Server So that I can remove this problem

(Please Comment "bad Question" if you think that this is bad Question  instead of downvoting I will remove this thread beacuse I need 80+ reputations to enter into android developer chat room on stackoverflow )

Peace

Comment: Maybe you can use a [ChildEventListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener) instead of a ValueEventListener? With a child listener you can check for specific actions like changes or deletes.

Comment: but my Database refernce point to "userPhone" hence when I use Child EventListener so its OnChild Added Method fires when A new Sender added
and When I remove messege so onChildChanged method fires not onChildRemoved method
see my server structure

Comment: should I attach onChildEventListerner to all friend's node?
like sender1,sender2...so on?

would it be better approach?

Comment: have you tried `if(!dataSnapshot.exists()) return;`

Comment: no but what it will do

Comment: put it at the start of onDataChange, that way you only process data if it exists and not when it's deleted

Comment: did u see where my database reference points?
Sir it is pointing to usersPhoneNumber 
and the data is being processed/modified is its child to child node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

to this:

```
.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

this way it will read data once only

Comment: But listening to messeges is a continuous process.

Comment: yes but this is the only way if you do not want ondatachange to fire again when there is changes: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: this data should be listened continuesly